# Identify values that dont match in all Nodes and Attributes: XSLT2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

I need to go over all the xml attributes and text nodes to identify existence of character from list and output the values the characters values that didnt match.

I am able to check the text() nodes but I am not able to perform a check on attributes.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:variable name="getDelimitersToUseNodes" select="('$' ,'#' ,'*' ,'~')[not(contains(current(),.))]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="getDelimitersToUseAttr" select="string-join(('$','#','*','~')[not(contains(@*/,.))],',')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="getDelimitersToUse" select="concat(string-join($getDelimitersToUseNodes,','),',',string-join($getDelimitersToUseAttr,','))"/>
    <!--xsl:variable name="delim" select="distinct-values($getDelimitersToUse,',')"/-->
    <xsl:value-of select="$getDelimitersToUse"/>
   </xsl:template>
```

My mocked up sample file is below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sample>
<test1 name="#theGoofy">My$#test</test1>
<test2 value="$#@">description test2*</test2>
</sample>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could process all those text and attribute nodes and make that same check as before. You haven't really said which output format you want, assuming text you could use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsl:param name="characters" as="xs:string*" select="'$' ,'#' ,'*' ,'~'"/>

<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//text() | //@*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text() | @*">
    <xsl:value-of select="'Text', ., 'does not contain', $characters[not(contains(current(), .))], '&#10;'"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get a result like

```
Text #theGoofy does not contain $ * ~ 
Text My$#test does not contain * ~ 
Text $#@ does not contain * ~ 
Text description test2* does not contain $ # ~
```

If you simply want to check all characters not contained in all text nodes and attribute nodes then an approach like

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsl:param name="characters" as="xs:string*" select="'$' ,'#' ,'*' ,'~'"/>

<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="nodes-to-inspect" as="node()*" select="//text() | //@*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="for $c in $characters return $c[not($nodes-to-inspect[contains(., $c)])]"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

should do.

Comment: Thank you. My output will be a variable which contains comma separated distinct values that are not in the file. In the above case, it should output '~'., which is passed on as output of the XSLT.

Comment: @ChipsnCoke, I have added a second sample that tries to output all characters not contained in any text or attribute nodes in one go.

Comment: This works beautifully. Thank you!!. Can you please explain to me how $c works. I have never defined and used in this way.